# JAXB Multiple Content for Element

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, dtd

I'm currently working on a txt-to-xml project. Basically what I'm doing is creating different XmlElements for some of the content. 
I got a DTD up and running and for now I'm creating a default xml, just to make sure every xml created is a valid xml (for the DTD given).
I'm mainly creating new Classes for every Element, which doesn't have a #PCDATA structure and it's working pretty fine so far.
Now I'm struggling with a problem:
I got the following in my DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT REACTION(#PCDATA | ACTOR*)>
```

What I'm looking for in my Text is something like:

> Prof. X clapped!

and I want to extract this into my XML as:

```
<REACTION>
  <ACTOR>Prof. X</ACTOR> clapped!
</REACTION>
```

So what I basically want is a String-Attribute within the ReactionClass which is devlares as XML-Element but holds an Actor-Attribute + Rest of the Text. I thought of something like:

```
String m_sText;
String m_sActor;

public ReactionClass(){ 
 this.Actor = "Prof. X";
 this.sText = this.m_sActor + " clapped!";
}

@XmlElement(name = "TEXT")
public String getM_sText(){ return this.m_sText; }

@XmlElement(name = "ACTOR")
public String getM_sActor(){ return this.m_sActor; }
```

For all other Nodes, such as the RootNode I created a RootNodeClass which holds different attributes, such as m_nLocation, m_nTime, m_nYear which are declared as XML-Elements, so the JAXB-Marshaller just builds up the XML on basis of these elements:

```
<ROOT>
 <TIME>09:00</TIME>
 <LOCATION>New York</TIME>
 <YEAR>1992</YEAR>
</ROOT>
```

I wanted to do the same with the REACTION-Node (like mentioned above), but when creating a new Class REACTION I'm getting sth. like:

```
<REACTION>
  <TEXT>Prof. X clapped!</TEXT>
  <ACTOR>Prof. X</ACTOR>
</REACTION>
```

How would I put them into one Element but still keep the Tags such as above?
If anybody got an idea how to manage this I would be very thankful!

Thanks Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, what you most probably need is [`@XmlMixed`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlMixed.html). You'll probably have a structure like:

```
@XmlMixed
@XmlElementRefs({
    @XmlElementRef(name="ACTOR", type=JAXBElement.class),
    ...})
List<Object> content;
```

With this you could put there `String`s and `JAXBElement<Actor>` to achieve so-called mixed content.

Next, you might consider turning your DTD into XML Schema first and compiling it - or compiling the DTD with XJC.

Finally, what you have is so-called "semi-structured data" which I think is not quite suitable for JAXB. JAXB works great for strong and clear structures, but if you have mixed stuff you get weird models that are hard to work with. I can't suggest an alternative though.